# Mostrar en un JSP distintos mensajes

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Estoy desarrollando un formulario con Spring y JSP,donde introducimos una contraseña y la validación de esta. La aplicación ya estaba desarrollada,entonces cuando se hace el submit, nos devuelve un Ok o Error en el cambio de la contraseña.

Ahora hay que añadir una vista intermedia que nos devuelva un mensaje que diga,por ejemplo, "Tu contraseña esta en proceso de cambio,por favor espere.Si quiere saber el resultado,no cierre este formulario" y despues de un tiempo aproximadamente 1 min,usando un `Thread.sleep()`,por debajo se esté realizando la operación de comprobar el estado y devuelva el Ok o Error..

Mi duda es, podria usar un return para cada mensaje o mensajes dentro de un mismo método(se que es "imposible pero por si acaso")? o deberia usar una llamada Ajax en el JSP? o deberia añadir otro JSP nuevo donde simplemente llame a ese nuevo mensaje?

Código JAVA donde invoco a los mensajes

```
log.debug("Comprobamos el estado de la cuenta de AD del usuario(Ok o Error),anadida espera de 1min");
            Thread.sleep(60000);
            request.setAttribute("message", Errors.CHECK_PASSWORD_MANAGED_SYS.getMessageName());
            getConnectorReplies();          
            String status = getConnectorReplies();          
            //Validacion de status de AD
            if (status.equals("Ok")) {
                request.setAttribute("message", Errors.CHANGE_PASSWORD_SUCCESS.getMessageName());
            } else {
                request.setAttribute("message", Errors.CHANGE_PASSWORD_FAILURE.getMessageName());
            }
    request.setAttribute("postbackURL", postbackURL);
return view;
```

Salida del JSP donde se observa el mensaje,en este caso solo muestra lo que retorna el view en el controlador.

```
<c:if test="${! empty requestScope.message}">
    <p class="forgot-username-box-msg" id="credentials">
        <spring:message code="${requestScope.message}" />
    </p>        
</c:if>
```

Comment: Agrega tu código por favor

Comment: una vez que se ejecuta un return, la funcion termina... asi que la respuesta seria no...

Comment: @BetaM gracias!

Comment: @gbianchi si,eso ya lo sabia pero no encuentro la manera de poder mostrar dentro de un mismo jsp(sin crear uno) varios mensajes, probablemente,por lo que he podido ver en la web..Ajax es algo con lo que se puede jugar pero hace mucho tiempo que no toco parte cliente

Comment: Entonces, tu pregunta es esa.. y no lo que pusiste en el titulo ;)

Comment: Iba a responder, pero luego he visto que no te molestas en marcar como correctas las respuestas que te dan... Revisa [help] y [ask].

Comment: @SJuan76 siento no haber marcado las respuestas,modifique el título pero desde la aplicación móvil no me dejaba hacerlo,aún así gracias por la info